# Cleanup and server restart script

Tags: bash, linux

I have written a simple script for managing our Tomcat and Apache instances for deployment. What this script basically does is, when called, it copies the `ROOT.war` from its `pwd` and pushes them to two Tomcat instances. Before that, it removes the old ROOT.war file and ROOT folder, restarts them, cleans the log files, restarts both Tomcat instances and Apache webserver (load-balancer and failover guy).

I have just pasted commands in a script and thought would learn more about it when I optimize this script, such as adding checks.

```
#!/bin/bash
sh /home/deploy/tomcatfirst/bin/catalina.sh stop
rm -rf /home/deploy/tomcatfirst/webapps/ROOT/
rm -rf /home/deploy/tomcatfirst/logs/
rm /home/deploy/tomcatfirst/webapps/ROOT.war
cp ROOT.war /home/deploy/tomcatfirst/webapps/
mkdir /home/deploy/tomcatfirst/logs


sh /home/deploy/tomcatfirst/bin/catalina.sh stop
rm -rf /home/deploy/tomcatsecond/webapps/ROOT/
rm /home/deploy/tomcatsecond/webapps/ROOT.war
rm -rf /home/deploy/tomcatsecond/logs/
mv ROOT.war /home/deploy/tomcatsecond/webapps/
mkdir /home/deploy/tomcatsecond/logs

sh /home/deploy/tomcatfirst/bin/catalina.sh start
sh /home/deploy/tomcatsecond/bin/catalina.sh start
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: No, it is not okay. Please do not edit updates to your code into the question. Post it as a new question if you want it reviewed.

Comment: But I want to make sure that the changes I did are also correct, depending upon suggestion as of now from choroba.

Comment: Then you'd be best to post it as a new question and get your changes reviewed too :-)

Comment: I've removed the _userscript_ tag from your post as userscripts are JavaScript addons designed to run in the browser, not a general term

Comment: `rm -rf /home/deploy/tomcatfirst/webapps/ROOT/` **never do this**. You need to delete the `war` and then _wait_ for Tomcat to clean up the deployed directory. Deleting the directory will likely cause the application to fail to shutdown, this can cause anything from annoying bugs in the next deployment (cached files in temp not cleared) to **data loss**.

Comment: @BoristheSpider it looks like he is shutting it down first.  How does it cause data loss in that scenario?

Comment: you are stopping the first tomcat twice.

Comment: @njzk2 : Script is already updated.. I will edit my post.

Comment: @BoristheSpider : I am stopping the server first... :-)

Comment: @WeareBorg yes. But you are not giving the server any _time_ to fully stop. Further, you are not deleting all the temp directories Tomcat creates so my points still stand. Undeploy webapplications cleanly, then stop your server if you you have to. Generally, you should never need to stop/start Tomcat - in fact replacing the `ROOT.war` will be enough in this case. If you do, you have some serious bugs in your application that need addressing...

Comment: @BoristheSpider : Okay, we thought this is the normal process, to stop the server, replace files and restart again. But I will replace the ROOT.war only next time. How much time will Tomcat need to update the ROOT folder based upon ROOT.war? Which temp directories you mean?

Comment: @WeareBorg depends on the application. It would take `f + u + d` where `f` is time to detect changes and autodeploy to trigger, `u` is time to undeploy and `d` is time to redeploy. For example, a simple application would be a matter of seconds; for my Jenkins server this would be a matter of minutes. Note `autodeploy` must be enabled, but it will be anyway given you are relying on it in your script. Temp directories live in `CATALINA_BASE/work`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider : That is too much time as our webapp is big. Would clearing `CATALINA_BASE/work` after stopping the server and then replacing ROOT.war and deleting ROOT dir enough?

Comment: @WeareBorg if you don't let Tomcat cleanly shut down before deleting you risk data loss. To cleanly shut down it must take at least `u + s`, where `u` is the same as [above](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116784/cleanup-and-server-restart-script?noredirect=1#comment217194_116784) and `s` is time for Tomcat to shutdown. It must then take at least `i + d` to start up, where `i` is Tomcat startup time and `d` is the same as above. I strongly suspect that `u + s + i + d` is _significantly_ more than `f + u + d` as `s + i > f` for any sane Tomcat installation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding checks? Just specify

```
set -e
```

at the beginning of the script. Should any command fail, the script will stop running, instead of wreaking more damage.

Using variables for repeated paths might make the script more readable.

```
tomcat1=/home/deploy/tomcatfirst
tomcat2=/home/deploy/tomcatsecond

sh "$tomcat1"/bin/catalina.sh stop
```

(BTW, shouldn't the second `stop` use $tomcat2?)

Once you have them, changing the above line to

```
set -eu
```

might be another improvement - the script will fail if a variable is not defined, which can happen if you mistype its name.

As the commands for both the server are the same, you can wrap them in a loop:

```
for tomcat /home/deploy/tomcat{first,second} ; do
    sh "$tomcat"/bin/catalina.sh stop
    # ...
done
```

If the servers are critical, you should specify the commands with full paths (e.g. `/bin/mkdir`).

Comment: I will check about assigning variables in bash as I don't know how. Haven't I already specified full paths?

Comment: @WeareBorg: Updated.

Comment: Found it. The updated script at bottom of main post. Just one thing more I can think of, how can I make sure that there is a ROOT.war file present at /home/deploy/ and then only start further operations?

Comment: Dont't include the final slash in the variable value. You use another one when using the variable, anyway. Double quote the variables - it's a good habit for cases when they can contain whitespace. To check file existence, use `[[ -f filename ]]`, but note that the file might be removed between the check and actual `cp`.

Comment: Script updated(3rd update) as per your suggestions. Kindly have a look.. Thank you.

Comment: How can I add a progress bar in between the for-loops with dot or percentage? Normal one I found.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest not purging logs - they can be useful for figuring out what happened.  Simply remove the rm line for the log directories.   Your webserver will simply append its new info to the existing log files, and something like logrotate should be used to keep the last X weeks.

Another option is to use the find command to purge old files but not the newest ones.

> /usr/bin/find /home/deploy/tomcatfirst/logs/  -mtime +7 -type f -exec
>   /bin/rm -f "{}" \;

This will delete any file in the given directory that is over 7 days old.

---

Also use exit status to figure out if you want to continue.  Simple example might be

> sh /home/deploy/tomcatfirst/bin/catalina.sh stop || exit 1

If the first command finishes with an exit level other than 0 it will stop the script.

Comment: Basically, `set -e` adds `|| exit 1` to all the commands that don't end in `|| something`.

Comment: We are only using the latest log and we keep an eye on it as we are testing as well. But deleting after the 7 days sounds like a good idea. My main problem was TOmcat was creating multiple log files based upon days/weeks/month.